# java inquiry on inputing values to vertexes/graph

Tags: java

i have a list of files, graph,adjlistnode,vertex, main and dict.txt file
I would like to build a java program whereby user can key in two words. After which the prgram will compare the 2 words for eg. cat → cot → dot → dog.

Based on my understanding, i have to make use of vertex.java and adjlistnode.java to throw in the words. after which i will do a checkoneworddiff method to see if there's any words that diffs by 1 character and then it will put it into the vertex. It will continue to search till it matches the 2nd word which is the final word.

Here's the question, what i dont understand is that i dont really know how do i call the starting word to the vertexes and from there generate the difference of the words and put them into the graph. and what's the use for the adjlistnode? The whole program should run on Breath First Search. Let me know if you got any other questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this as answer because I don't have the rep for a comment.

First off, its really hard to answer any of this without knowing what `Vertex` and `AdjlistNode` actually do.  If you for some reason have to use those classes, its downright impossible.  But you shouldn't need those to do a simple BFS search...

Comment: Hey, vertex contains a setword and getword method while adjlistnode contains the vertexnumber, getvertex and setvertex number methods. Any other information u require?